# Does reference consume disk space?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question.

Lets say i have 2 tables

`Parent(nameParent, children)`

Clearly if i have:

```
Parent

'Mary' | 'John'
'Mary' | 'Dan'
'Mary' | 'Chris'
```

I have duplicate `nameParent` entries. So If i have:

```
Parent(nameParent)
'Mary'

Child(nameChild, nameParent)
'John' | 'Mary'
'Dan'  | 'Mary'
'Chris'| 'Mary'
```

Is it true that this is more efficient than the 1st example because `nameParent` is a pointer to parent Mary rather than an entry consuming space on the disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a Names table to eliminate data redundancy, while improving data integrity.

```
create table Names (
  ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE (Name)
);

create table ChildParentNames (
  ChildName MEDIUMINT,
  ParentName MEDIUMINT,
  FOREIGN KEY (ChildName) REFERENCES Names(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ParentName) REFERENCES Names(ID)
)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Since the reference to "efficient" is rather ambiguous, I think this is  quite an appropriate answer, especially since @Mythul chose it a the correct response.

Comment: You do not address efficiency or physical space at all. Your solution has no improvement over the model I or Tom presented. Just because it is chosen as the correct answer does not necessarily make it the *best* answer.

Comment: It is the correct answer because it presents a solution in 3rd normal form, which yours does not. Grow up.

Answer (score 2):

Efficient? Somewhat. You should focus more on the design and performance rather than physical disk space. It does provide for referential integrity though. A typical design for this question would be something along the lines of:

```
id | name  | parent_id
1    Mary    NULL
2    John    1
3    Dan     1
4    Chris   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Disk space wise, a `VARCHAR` simply takes (roughly) the max amount of bytes you've supplied (`VARCHAR(16)` always takes twice as much as `VARCHAR(8)`), an `INT` is constant 4 bytes, etc. It's easy to estimate the amount of disk space per row (minus indices) by just summing up all the fields:

```
INT id           -- 4 bytes
CHAR name(15)    -- 15 bytes
TEXT description -- variable, depending on the content
```

Ideally, avoid duplicate data by never storing the same string twice. In your case, it's probably best to replace the `nameParent` column with a numeric ID pointing at the parent table.

That said, indices also take up disk space, at roughly two times the size of a field times the amount of rows. Let's assume you made the `id` key (`int`) a primary key, with 2048 rows it would take up roughly 16 kilobytes.

When estimating total disk usage of a table per row, sum the size of all fields, then just add the size of the indices. This will give you a rough estimation.

---

**The actually important part**

Of course, disk space really isn't important for databases, and you should always focus on performance instead. Unless your tables are going to get VERY big (million of rows), it really isn't going to be an issue at all.

In your specific case, just make a `person` table with the fields `id`, `parent` and `name`. Set the `parent` field to `NULL` for those without a parent, and let the children use the `parent` field to specify who their parent is. Then you've got everything in one table, you can represent entire family lines, and it's still very easy.

Comment: A `VARCHAR` in MySQL takes either one or two bytes plus the CONTENT of the column, not the defined length. If your column is over 255 characters, two bytes are stored to indicate length, if less than 255, one byte. This means a VARCHAR(8) and a VARCHAR(100) containing 'Mary' will both only consume five bytes of real disk space.

Comment: @cairnz Are you absolutely sure about that? As far as I know the way you describe it goes for `TEXT` and `BLOB`, but not for `CHAR`.

Comment: A `CHAR` is different from a `VARCHAR`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html